# JavaScript Mouse Click addEventListener Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

That `addEventListener("click", forgotPassword)` is not working when `// ADD PANEL TO BODY` event is calling.
Please Help to fix this.

**Javascript:**

```
var forgot_password_btn = document.querySelector("#forgot_password");
var theme_panel = "<div id=\"change-theme\"><a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"dark\">DARK</a><a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"light\">LIGHT</a></div>";

if (forgot_password_btn) {
    forgot_password_btn.addEventListener("click", forgotPassword);
}

function forgotPassword() {
    console.log("clicked");
}

// ADD PANEL TO BODY
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.innerHTML += theme_panel;
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="forgot_password">Forgot</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM is not ready when you are fetching the forgot_password element. Therefore, no binding is made. Put the logic inside the onload event:

```
function forgotPassword() {
    console.log("clicked");
}

// ADD PANEL TO BODY
window.onload = function () {

    var forgot_password_btn = document.querySelector("#forgot_password");
    var theme_panel = "<div id=\"change-theme\"><a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"dark\">DARK</a><a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"light\">LIGHT</a></div>";

    if (forgot_password_btn) {
        forgot_password_btn.addEventListener("click", forgotPassword);
    }
};
```

Also, you should avoid inserting HTML content directly in the JS like that. Put it in the HTML or use templates.

Comment: Even if you put it inside `DOMContentLoaded`, it does not work. You can console `forgot_password_btn` and you get it there. Seems to be some other issue. Putting it inside `onload` callback will work but I am looking for convincing justification. Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/8hz1bpt4/3/

Comment: The issue is the "document.body.innerHTML += theme_panel;" line. It messes with the handlers. Like I said, it is not a good way to insert HTML and will likely cause other issues down the road.

Comment: May be this is better way to do so as `document.body.innerHTML += theme_panel;
` will kill the event listeners. https://jsfiddle.net/8hz1bpt4/6/

Comment: **Thanks for the comments.** That `insertAdjacentHTML` also work.